How can I draw the Bitmap of a Direct 2D BitmapRenderTarget to a WicRenderTarget using SharpDX?
I'm attempting to create a BitmapRenderTarget, draw to it, and then draw the Bitmap created to a WicRenderTarget, the end goal being to then save that as a png. The problem, the code fails when I attempt to draw the BitmapRenderTarget's Bitmap to the created WicRenderTarget without any explanation. How can I achieve this?
Size2F size = new((float)(_deviceContext.Size.Width * Zoom), (float)(_deviceContext.Size.Height * Zoom));
BitmapRenderTarget bitmapRenderTarget = new(_deviceContext, CompatibleRenderTargetOptions.None, size)
{
    DotsPerInch = size,
    AntialiasMode = AntialiasMode.PerPrimitive
};
bitmapRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
bitmapRenderTarget.Clear(new RawColor4(1, 1, 1, 1));
bitmapRenderTarget.DrawLine(new RawVector2(0, 0), new RawVector2(100, 100), new SolidColorBrush(bitmapRenderTarget, new RawColor4(0, 0, 0, 1)), 1);
bitmapRenderTarget.EndDraw();

_imagingFactory = new();
_wicBitmap = new SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap(_imagingFactory, (int)(_deviceContext.Size.Width * Zoom), (int)(_deviceContext.Size.Height * Zoom), SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPBGRA, BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnLoad);

_wicRenderTarget = new(bitmapRenderTarget.Factory, _wicBitmap, new RenderTargetProperties(bitmapRenderTarget.PixelFormat))
{
    DotsPerInch = size,
    AntialiasMode = AntialiasMode.PerPrimitive
};
_wicRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
_wicRenderTarget.DrawBitmap(bitmapRenderTarget.Bitmap, 1, BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);

_wicRenderTarget.EndDraw();

Bitmap = Bitmap.FromWicBitmap(_deviceContext, _wicBitmap);


Do you have a small reproducing project? Details matter

I update Step 2 and Step 3 in my code:
    // Step 1: Create and draw to the BitmapRenderTarget.
    Size2F size = new((float)(_deviceContext.Size.Width * Zoom), (float)(_deviceContext.Size.Height * Zoom));
    BitmapRenderTarget bitmapRenderTarget = new(_deviceContext, CompatibleRenderTargetOptions.None, size)
    {
        DotsPerInch = size,
        AntialiasMode = AntialiasMode.PerPrimitive
    };
    
    bitmapRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
    bitmapRenderTarget.Clear(new RawColor4(1, 1, 1, 1));
    
    // Draw with cached brushes
    bitmapRenderTarget.DrawLine(new RawVector2(0, 0), new RawVector2(100, 100), new SolidColorBrush(bitmapRenderTarget, new RawColor4(0, 0, 0, 1)), 1);
    bitmapRenderTarget.EndDraw();
    
    // Step 2: Create a WIC bitmap.
var imagingFactory = new ImagingFactory2();
var wicBitmap = new SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap(imagingFactory, (int)(_deviceContext.Size.Width * Zoom), (int)(_deviceContext.Size.Height * Zoom), SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPBGRA, BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnLoad);

// Step 3: Copy the pixel data from the BitmapRenderTarget to the WIC bitmap.
using (var bitmapFromRenderTarget = bitmapRenderTarget.Bitmap)
{
    DataStream dataStream;
    var dataRectangle = bitmapFromRenderTarget.Map(MapOptions.Read, out dataStream);

    var wicBitmapLock = wicBitmap.Lock(BitmapLockFlags.Write);
    try
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < dataRectangle.Height; y++)
        {
            dataStream.Position = y * dataRectangle.Pitch;
            wicBitmapLock.Data.Position = y * wicBitmapLock.Stride;

            dataStream.CopyTo(wicBitmapLock.Data, dataRectangle.Width);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        bitmapFromRenderTarget.Unmap();
        wicBitmapLock.Dispose();
    }
}
    
    // Step 4: Save the WIC bitmap to a file.
    using (var stream = new WICStream(imagingFactory, "output.png", SharpDX.IO.NativeFileAccess.Write))
    using (var pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(imagingFactory))
    {
        pngEncoder.Initialize(stream);
    
        using (var frameEncoder = new BitmapFrameEncode(pngEncoder))
        {
            frameEncoder.Initialize();
            frameEncoder.SetSize(wicBitmap.Size.Width, wicBitmap.Size.Height);
            frameEncoder.SetPixelFormat(ref SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPBGRA);
            frameEncoder.WriteSource(wicBitmap);
            frameEncoder.Commit();
        }
        pngEncoder.Commit();
    }
    
    // Cleanup resources.
    wicBitmap.Dispose();
    wicRenderTarget.Dispose();
    bitmapRenderTarget.Dispose();
    imagingFactory.Dispose();


My problem is that I'm needing to specifically draw to a BitmapRenderTarget first. I have a lot of cached brushes that are created with that DeviceContext that I don't want to have to remake and aren't working with the WicRenderTarget.

I saw the update but unfortunately it's failing right at the same spot as mine:
wicRenderTarget.DrawBitmap(bitmapFromRenderTarget, 1.0f, BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);


This doesn't work for me. There doesn't appear to be any method for a direct 2d bitmap named Map.
